# Maxif equivalent in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Say I have the following table in excel:
[image]

How would I go about creating a function that would select the Fruit with longest  shelf life? Order is important with this list, so sorting is not an option. The formula also has to be limited to one cell, I cannot drag and drop equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the **Array formula**:

```
=INDEX(A1:A100,SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C100=MAX(IF(B1:B100="fruit",C1:C100,"")))*(B1:B100="fruit")*ROW(1:100)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

This is based on:

- getting the max life for fruits from *MAX(IF())*
- getting the row number from *SUMPRODUCT()*
- getting the name from *INDEX()*